# dll files created in Visual C++ be used in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, interop

I am creating a dll file in visual C++ through Dynamic Link Library project. I know i can import this dll thorugh object browser in C#. I want to know whether i can use those functions without any issues, since i am programming in 2 different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your C++ DLL written in managed C++?  If so then you should be able to use it by just adding a reference to it from your C# project.  Otherwise you want to look into [.NET Interop topics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177552(VS.80).aspx) to learn how to use both.